# How to run C# 7.1 compiler from the command line instead of IDE?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I just got me a new C# book, it's a very good read. I found that my Visual Studio 2017 express IDE can compile C# 7.1 or lower. I am really a notepad and command ine compiler kind of guy though. I use NotePad++ and I compile my code with a command line compiler (so long as the project is not too large...).

I was trying to find where the command line based C# 7.1 compiler was installed on my system? Do you guys know where it is generally installed?

I did poke around a bit, and I found this:
C:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe

I don't know what the C# version number is for the above file path is? I tried csc.exe /version but to no avail. Can you guys help me get a hold of a C# 7.1 command line based compiler?
Thanks!

- Erik W.

Comment: Typing `csc /?` at a command prompt shows all relevant options. Scrolling to the top of that command window shows the version. Does that help? Questions asking us to find an off-site resource are off-topic here, which would include *help me get a hold of* questions. You may want to read the [help] pages.

Comment: It reads 2.3.2.62116, but I am not sure what that corresponds to, like C# 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, or 7.1? I am kind of new to .NET, I am confused.

Comment: What's confusing? *I found that my Visual Studio 2017 express can compile C# 7.1 or lower*; isn't `2.3.2.62116` lower than `7.1`? What **specific problem** are you trying to solve? Do you have code in the *very good read* book that won't compile with the version you have installed?

Comment: I just want to know what I am doing for getting a new job. But I found that the version 2.3.2 is the current version (or Roslyn) for the Microsoft Compilers.  But, I did find if your run /langversion:7.1 myCode.cs, you can force it to compile C# 7.1. I will post the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

For the path link I posted:

```
C:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe
```

you run:

```
csc.exe /langversion:7.1 myCSharpFile.cs
```

and it will compile the code in C# 7.1

Comment: Run: csc /langversion:foo will report the language versions supported by the compiler. For me, sadly, it says: "ISO-1, ISO-2, Default or an integer in range 1 to 6". So no 7.1 features for me.